# Command line SOCKS tool for Windows

Tags: open-source

I am looking for a software with these specifications:

- For **Windows**
- **Console**, no GUI
- Supports at least **SOCKS4** (SOCKS5 OK, ofc)
- **Portable**, no installation required (preferable single file)
- Single file, self-contained.
- **Free**. Open source desirable

Something light. Like a portable `ncat` with SOCKS support.

The tool should be able to proxy connections, so it can be used with e.g. `ssh -D` on the other side.

Comment: Ok, but what should it do? I think a command line socks4 connector? Or a tcp proxy between a socks4 service and a tcp port?

Comment: (afaik in the Linux world there are libraries to wrap the tcp calls to socks. I don't know if they also on Win exists, but they are surely possible because dll hooking goes nearly on the same way, altough with very different api calls, as on Linux). I hope you get an useful answer!

Comment: ((yet another side remark: in my experience, socks5 is better supported since some years as socks4. Even ssh in cygwin can connect over socks5))